# One To Many Relationship in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I've three tables to relate as far as I know they have one to many relationship

```
Pet Table
id
pet_name
pet_type_id
```

```
Pet Type Table
id
pet_type
```

```
Breed Table
id
Breed
pet_type_id
```

```
1. Pet Type has many breeds
2. Breeds belongs to Pet Type
3. Pet Type has many Pets
4. Pet belongs to many pet types
```

I've created the following Relationship in laravel

Pet Model

```
public function breed_type()
{
   $this->belongsTo(PetType::class);
}
```

Pet Type Model

```
public function breed()
{
   $this->belongsTo(Breed::class);
}

public function pet()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Pet::class);
}
```

Breed Model

```
public function petType() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(PetType::class);
}
```

I want to show a form to the user there will be a drop down which will show the type of Pet and on the Basis of Pet Type another drop down will be populated which will show all the breeds of the above Pet type. And then all the data from the form will be saved in Pets Table.

Now I want to show all the data stored in the Pets table. When i query the db for the breed_type it shows the relation but value is null. I want to get the name of the pet type and also the pet breed because we have relations.

But it is still not working kindly guide me where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: you should also explain what is your expected result or what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise it will be difficult for us to understand

Comment: @TanvirAhmed hope it will be clear now what i want..

Comment: @WaheedSindhani, did you ever try with my post below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current table structure:

> Pet Model

```
public function pet_type()
{
  $this->belongsTo(PetType::class);
}
```

> Pet Type Model

```
public function breed()
{
   $this->hasMany(Breed::class);
}

public function pet()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Pet::class);
}
```

> Breed Model

```
public function petType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PetType::class);
}
```

Comment: This is my pet_type migration
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pet_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('pet_type');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: Bread can only have one pettype based on your current structure.

Comment: yes i want that there will be a list showing the type of pets like dog, cat and when the user select one type then another drop down will be shown which will select all the breeds based on that type

Comment: your solution worked but how can i get breed type based on type from pet_type relationship bcs there is no foreign key in pet_type table

Comment: you can check hasManyThrough relation

Comment: `$pet = Pet::with('pet_type)->get();`
it returns the relationship but when i try to get 
`$pet->pet_type;`
it gives me an error undefined property.  
but when i try to get only one records it works then whats is the problem here.